# how to get border bottom visible when link is active

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I am designing bootstrap 3
How to get border bottom when the link is active ?
In which css3 code I have to mention.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav >  a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav >  a:hover {
color: #354242;
background-color: #fff;} .navbar-nav { padding-top: 5px; }

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus { border-bottom: 2px solid #E74C3C; outline: none; } .navbar { min-height: inherit; margin-bottom: 0px; }
```

Comment: working fine in your given link right?

Comment: I have update the question...sorry for the mistake. It comes in other carousel also if i give that type of code           https://baigny.github.io/HRService/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, i tried in your link using firebug, it works fine.

```
.navbar-right li .active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #E74C3C;
}
```

Comment: I want underline to be visible when a section get activated..or in otherwords when we click on a menu. that does not works..

Comment: thanks!! ...One more related to this...when the page loaded home section is shown.. So shall i insert <li class ="active">home </li>..or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Just by default add active class to your home section like this <a href="#features" class="active">Home</a>

Comment: thanks once again..I have one more doubt but not related to this topic..but in same project? shall i ask here?? or in another question??

Comment: better to add another question